# What is `abc` prefix on R.dimen fields?

Tags: android

I wonder what is the meaning of `abc` prefix on `R.dimen` fields.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.dimen.html

Can I use those values in my `layout.xml` or somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a prefix used by AppCompat to minimize naming conflicts with your code and other libraries. It is an abbreviation of `ActionBarCompat`.

You can find the commit that initially added this prefix to AppCompat [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/ee7c9fb).